# Drupal 8 variable_get

Tags: 8, configuration

I have some code in Drupal 7 what are using variable_get. Now I would like to write the code in Drupal 8. So I was reading [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/1667896) but its didn't help me a lot.

How to write this code in Drupal 8 from code in Drupal 7?

```
$types = array_values(variable_get('test_content_types', array()));
```

or this

```
'#default_value' => variable_get('test_content_types', array()),
```

Some suggestion.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Drupal 7

```
 $data =  variable_get('test_content_types');
```

In Drupal 8

```
 $data = \Drupal::state()->get('test_content_types');
```

For more information about about "get", "set", "delete" visit - [Step 5: How to upgrade D7 variables to D8's state system](https://www.drupal.org/node/1787318).

Comment: Thank you @darol100 .. The link is nice.. Now I understend. So I can write  $data = \Drupal::state()->get('test_content_types', array());

Comment: Be aware that in D8 there is a difference between state and config. As noted on https://www.drupal.org/developing/api/8/configuration: "Configuration is a place to store information that you would want to synchronize from development to production. This information is often created during site building and is not typically generated by regular users during normal site operation.

You should use the State API, not configuration, for storing local variables that shouldn't travel between instances. Use state for hidden system values, and if you never want to deploy it between environments."

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer is half the answer.  As marcvangend notes, there are two options in Drupal 8 for what used to be stored in the variables table and was stored and retrieved with `variable_set()` and `variable_get()`.  The first, documented in darol100's answer, is the [State API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/state-api/overview).

The second is the [Configuration API](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/configuration-api-overview) and should be used in most cases where you have a configuration form.  It requires at [minimum](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/configuration-api/simple-configuration-api) in your module a configuration installation file, for example `config/install/example.settings.yml`.  For a single piece of configuration (with multiple potential values), that file could just contain for example:

`test_content_types:
  - article`

And then use the value with:

```
$types = \Drupal::config('example.settings')->get('test_content_types');
```

Or change the stored values with:

```
\Drupal::service('config.factory')
  ->getEditable('example.settings')
  ->set('test_content_types', ['article', 'page'])
  ->save();
```

See also the the Drupal 8 documentation for [D7 to D8 configuration upgrades](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/converting-drupal-7-modules-to-drupal-8/step-4-convert-drupal-7-variables-to-drupal-8) and [using configuration in modules](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/defining-and-using-your-own-configuration-in-drupal-8).

Comment: For me, this is the correct answer to the question. I'm currently making the transition from Drupal 7 and it helped me a lot.